# Set a limit on a registration form

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have an asp classic Event registration jquery form. what I would like to do is display a number spaces available on my registration page like "Available Space: 20" after user filled up the form they will get an email and also we have an XML file which the info is stored there.
Is there a way to read the XML file with JS,JQ or ASP  and show how many available written on a xml?

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to learn basics then you can search [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CFsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fxml%2Fxml_parser.asp&ei=vse0T6aoL9GGrAehhLiqDA&usg=AFQjCNGX91XKsNjBfmNt9otkl28DgENJmg&sig2=pUOKvldXcuWjZ7VlMtPI2g)
also you can find a working example [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CFsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fxml%2Fxml_parser.asp&ei=vse0T6aoL9GGrAehhLiqDA&usg=AFQjCNGX91XKsNjBfmNt9otkl28DgENJmg&sig2=pUOKvldXcuWjZ7VlMtPI2g)